# Warning: Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to PK

Tags: java, object, warnings

How can I remove the warning from "`id = (PK) m.invoke(obj, (Object []) null);`"

```
    private PK getId(T obj) {
    PK id = null;
    for (Field f : type.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (f.getAnnotation(Id.class) != null) {
            String name = f.getName();
            String method = "get" + name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
            try {
                Method m = type.getDeclaredMethod(method, (Class<?>) null);
                id = (PK) m.invoke(obj, (Object []) null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return id;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming PK is a generic type in your class

```
class MyClass<PK> {
```

Due to Java type erasure, the type PK is not available at runtime.  But if you accept in your constructor a `Class<PK>` instance, then you can get around this by calling `klass.cast(...)`

```
class MyClass<PK> {
    private final Class<PK> keyClass;
    MyClass(Class<PK> keyClass) {
         this.keyClass = keyClass;
    }

    PK getKey() {
        return keyClass.cast(...);
    }
}
```

If for whatever reason you can't get a reference to the actual runtime type of PK, then you have little recourse but to suppress the warning.

Answer (score 0):

`Method#invoke` returns an `Object` so you only have 2 ways to get rid of the warning:

- Declare `id` as `Object`
- add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` before the method declaration.

Comment: It returns a PK so you can't declare id as a Object

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

before method declaration